# spec test export csv files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, specifications

I am generating a csv export file using this code, which inherence from the report class

```
class Reports::Donors < Reports::Report

  def initialize(args = {})
    super(args)
    @campaign = args[:report]
    @campaign.report.data[:donations][:tiers].each do |contribution_tier|
      @data = []
      tmp_arr = []
      tmp_arr << ActionController::Base.helpers.number_to_currency(contribution_tier.amount_in_dollars)
      @data << tmp_arr

      @data << ['Date','User Name','Amount in dollars','Address','Email','State']

      contribution_tier.contributions.sort{|a,b| a.amount_in_dollars <=> b.amount_in_dollars}.each do |c|
        tmp_arr = []
        tmp_arr << c.created_at
        tmp_arr << c.user.full_name
        tmp_arr << ActionController::Base.helpers.number_to_currency(c.amount_in_dollars)
        tmp_arr << c.user.address
        tmp_arr << c.user.email
        tmp_arr << c.state.titleize
        @data << tmp_arr
      end
        if @campaign.report.data[:donations][:non_tier][:sum] > 0
          @campaign.campaign.open_contributions.sort{|a,b| a.amount_in_dollars <=> b.amount_in_dollars}.each do |c|
            tmp_arr = []
            tmp_arr << c.created_at
            tmp_arr << c.user.full_name
            tmp_arr << ActionController::Base.helpers.number_to_currency(c.amount_in_dollars)
            tmp_arr << c.user.address
            tmp_arr << c.user.email
            tmp_arr << c.state.titleize
            @data << tmp_arr
          end
         end
      end
    end
```

end

And I need to write a spec for this, but I don't know from were to start.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW -- looking at a method afterward and trying to come up with a spec leads to frustration, guilt, and binges. If you were to create this using TDD, it would be broken up into small methods that were easy to verify.

Hint: break up your code into small methods. test those methods.